# VBA XMLHTTP request doesn't capture dynamic HTML response

Tags: javascript, html, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get a specific dynamic figure from a webpage to excel, I managed to gather all the website get response into a "all" variable which I am supposed to parse to extract my numbers, except for when I check the string variable I can see everything but the required dynamic figure! :) "the attached phot shows the dynamic figure at the very instant was 2.19",
any ideas why I am capturing every thing, would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance

My thoughts:
1.I am guessing is the figures are injected by JavaScript or a server side that might be executing after my XMLHTTP request is processed maybe! if this is the case or else I need your expertise

2. the website doesn't response unless it sees a specific Html request header, so I might need to mimic the headers of Chrome, I don't know how they look like?

Please see below my code and a screenshot for the figure I would like to capture

```
'Tools>refrences>microsoft xml v3 must be refrenced
Public Function GetWebSource(ByRef URL As String) As String
    Dim xml As IXMLHTTPRequest
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        GetWebSource = .responseText
    End With
    Set xml = Nothing
End Function

Sub ADAD()
Dim all As Variant
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim URL As String

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
all = GetWebSource("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/CRYPTOCAP-ADA.D/")


pos = InStr(all, "tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last")
testString = Mid(all, pos, 200)
'I am supposed to see the dynamic figure within the TAG but it is not showing!!
Debug.Print testString

End Sub
```

[HTML for Dynamic Required values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcI16.jpg)

Comment: You likely need to use browser automation for this type of task.  either automate IE directly or maybe look at using selenium.

Comment: Any starting point please?

Comment: It's using a websocket to update. If you want to get fancy you might find something in here: https://www.example-code.com/excel/websocket.asp . Personally, I would use a language with a nicely presented API for such things such as Python. Also, have you checked whether the company provides any public APIs? If you go [here](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/CRYPTOCAP-ADA.D/ideas/) you can use Network > ws > Messages to monitor the traffic across the socket. My guess is that there will be security measures to prevent grabbing this.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Williams This is a code using selenium (But it seems doesn't do the trick of getting the value)

### PhantomJS Selenium VBA

```
Sub Test()
    Dim bot As Selenium.PhantomJSDriver
    Set bot = New Selenium.PhantomJSDriver
    With bot
        .Get "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/CRYPTOCAP-ADA.D/"
        .Wait 2000
        Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last']").Attribute("outerHTML")
    End With
End Sub
```

### Chrome VBA Selenium

It seems using `PhantomJS` doesn't work properly, so here's a Chrome version of selenium in VBA

```
Private bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
    Set bot = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    With bot
        .Start
        .Get "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/CRYPTOCAP-ADA.D/"
        Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last']").Text 'Attribute("outerHTML")
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

### Python Solution

And this is the working python code that my tutor @QHarr provided in comments

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome("D:/Webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
d.get('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/CRYPTOCAP-ADA.D/')
d.find_element_by_css_selector('.tv-symbol-price-quote__value.js-symbol-last').text
```

Comment: `d.FindElementByCss('.tv-symbol-price-quote__value.js-symbol-last').text`

Comment: That is a good start but I am still getting empty div tags without the values using both ByXpath and ByCSS? still looking for a fix

Comment: @QHarr The same problem when using CSS.

Comment: Odd. Worked fine with python and selenium. Also, I examined the websocket and could see the data.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that I used `PhantomJS`?!!

Comment: @QHarr can you provide Python code please?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Did you use /ideas?

Comment: As for the python code, I got this `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css'`. I added waiting time for 5 seconds and got the same output.

Comment: As for the VBA code, I tried to use /ideas as you did and it returns the same empty result.

Comment: The python code should have `find_element_by_css_selector`. That worked fine for me. But as for VBA selenium, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. I started amending for vba. Corrected paste: https://pastebin.com/6WingSUe